# how to solve this with android waiting for service surfaceflinger?

Tags: android

Every time I start my eclipse in my Log cat it continue prints one message waiting for service surfaceflinger with green text and I run my project but it does not show anything Log cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your DDMS try to reset adb and run your project may be it will work